# Replicate identical tuples to N

Tags: python

I have identical tuples of (0, 1) assigned to define limits for 3 input values:

```
bounds = ((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1))
```

Is there a Pythonic way to assign same tuples for N inputs? For example:

```
bounds = ((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), ...Nth(0, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks @Jean-François Fabre and jonrsharpe for your remarks. That question "How do you create a list of repeated tuples in Python?" is very hard to understand for my purpose. I'd like to keep this question as focused and specific as it is not a duplicate.

Comment: it is a duplicate, but the answers given here are good & upvoted, so use the ones here (Peter answer is very good). But it _is_ a duplicate (maybe we can find better ones to add to the list)

Comment: Thanks @Jean-François Fabre appreciate your input :)

Comment: when closing as a duplicate, I feel the duty not to be too hard on users. This isn't a punishment (I even upvoted your question because it's much clearer than the "original" question), this is helping them / helping the site to avoid more answers to be posted. Peter's answer is excellent and was posted before closure: that's fine by me.

Comment: Understood @Jean-François Fabre yes agree :) appreciate your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can multiply a sequence to get N shallow copies of its contents:

```
bounds = ((0, 1),) * n
```

This is fine for tuples of ints or other immutable data structures containing only immutable types, but will cause [surprising behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) if you use it for mutable data structures like lists - you get a sequence of n references to the same list, because it's a shallow copy. In that case, a comprehension is the most idiomatic way to create n independent objects:

```
mutable_bounds = [[0, 1] for _ in range(n)]
```

Comment: Very elegant solution indeed @Peter DeGlopper! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
bounds = ((0, 1),) * N
```

Works for any iterable, BTW: `'1111' == '1' * 4`.

Comment: works _properly_ for any _immutable_ iterable. For mutable iterables, it repeats the same reference over again: not what anyone would want.

Comment: For immutables as well, I presume, and every time you forbid someone to want something, god kills a smoothly running process. :(

Comment: it repeats the references for tuples, yes, but you cannot change a tuple in the list without changing the reference: no risk of changing all elements by changing one. Try `x = [[]] * 10` then `x[0].append(1)` and see what I'm talking about (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Trust me I know what you're talking about, and IMO no language's legal semantics can be deemed unwantable by everyone.

Answer (score 2):

[**itertools.repeat()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) alternative:

```
import itertools

n = 5    # coefficient
bounds = tuple(itertools.repeat((0,1), n))
print(bounds)
```

The output:

```
((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the multiplication operator (`*`) on lists of tuples. For example:

```
((0,1),) * 3
```

yields:

```
((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks @leonardoandrade for your input.